# Remove first instance of sub-string from row if found in the previous row in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, substring

I'm doing a data analysis of web-scraped Pokemon stats. How can i remove the first instance of "Venusaur" in row #3 so it just says "Mega Venusaur"? I'm thinking a function that compares the previous "name" in the row but how to access the first instance of the name? And have this applied to all "megas" in the rest of the list.

```
name_instance = for Name in Names
poke_df.loc[poke_df['Name'].str.contains(name_instance), 'Name'] = 'Mega'+name_instance
```

```
NationalNo  Name    Type    Type_1  Type_2  HP  Attack  Defense Sp_Atk  Sp_Def  Speed   Total   Stat_Avg

2   003 Venusaur    [Grass, Poison] Grass   Poison  80  82  83  100 100 80  525 87
3   003 Venusaur Mega Venusaur  [Grass, Poison] Grass   Poison  80  100 123 122 120 80  625 104
4   004 Charmander  [Fire, None]    Fire    None    39  52  43  60  50  65  309 51
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition to your linking:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Venusaur', 'Venusaur Mega Venusaur', 'Charmander']})
df['Prev Name'] = df['Name'].shift(fill_value='')


def get_name(row):
    name = row['Name']
    prev_name = row['Prev Name']
    if name.startswith(prev_name):
        return name[len(prev_name):]
    return name


df['Name'] = df.apply(get_name, axis=1)
df.drop(columns='Prev Name', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output is:

```
        Name
0        Venusaur
1   Mega Venusaur
2      Charmander
```

Comment: I'm looking for something more generic, to loop through the whole list for all "megas".